# Unable to pass any parameters when creating an object in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to create an object of the "Borrower" class. I tried all combinations of parameters but it's giving me an error for everything. Not sure what is happening. The way its setup is String,int,int but when I give it in this format, it gives me error.

Here is an image of the parameter screen:
[image]

The code for the borrower class is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Borrower {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int age;
    private ArrayList<Book> booklist;

    public Borrower(String[] info) {
        this.setName(info[0]);
        this.setId(Integer.parseInt(info[1]));
        this.setAge(Integer.parseInt(info[2]));

        this.booklist = new ArrayList<Book>();
        if(info.length == 5) { 
            this.booklist.add(new Book(info[3], info[4], ""));
        } else if(info.length == 6) { 
            this.booklist.add(new Book(info[3], info[4], info[5]));
        } else if(info.length == 7) { 
            this.booklist.add(new Book(info[3], info[4], ""));
            this.booklist.add(new Book(info[5], info[6], ""));
        } else if(info.length == 8) {
            this.booklist.add(new Book(info[3], info[4], info[5]));
            this.booklist.add(new Book(info[6], info[7], info[8]));
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public ArrayList<Book> getBooklist() {
        return booklist;
    }
    public boolean addBook(Book book) {
        if(this.booklist.size() < 2) {
            this.booklist.add(book);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean returnBook() {
        if(this.booklist.size() > 0) {
            this.booklist.remove(0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(this.getName());
        sb.append("," + this.getId());
        sb.append("," + this.getAge());
        for(Book book : booklist) {
            sb.append("," + book);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Update: Error Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: "but it's giving me an error for everything." - what error? Please don't leave us guessing. It's not clear to non-bluej users what you're doing here, either - normally you'd create an instance by calling the constructor *in code*.

Comment: Could you add the code calling the constructor?

Comment: Hi, i've added the error screenshot too! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it this way

```
{"Arvind" , "1" , "2"}
```

Enter the above in the dialog box.
Basically `{}` was the missing identifier.

Comment: Its giving me another error saying"Incompatible types":int cannot be converted to java.lang.string when i enter the above

Comment: I am very sorry. Apologies

Comment: @ArvindSuryanarayana  sorry

Comment: Thank you! Worked! Can't believe it was just that!